# C# rearrange List by pattern

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting, collections

I have a `List<TimeAndCode>` of objects. Every object contains a `Code` and a `TimeSpan` value.

```
public struct TimeAndCode {
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

The occuring codes are pre defined as `"CO"`, `"GO"` and `"BT"`.

When the `Time` property hits the same value, the order of the list needs to be in a certan format. e.g. (JSON representation for readability)

```
[
    {"Time" : "08:00:00", "Code" : "CO" },
    {"Time" : "09:00:00", "Code" : "GO" },
    {"Time" : "09:30:00", "Code" : "CO" },
    {"Time" : "09:30:00", "Code" : "GO" },
    {"Time" : "09:30:00", "Code" : "CO" },
    {"Time" : "09:30:00", "Code" : "GO" },
    {"Time" : "09:30:00", "Code" : "BT" },
    {"Time" : "12:30:00", "Code" : "CO" },
    {"Time" : "12:30:00", "Code" : "GO" },
    {"Time" : "13:30:00", "Code" : "CO" },
    {"Time" : "13:30:00", "Code" : "GO" },
    {"Time" : "13:30:00", "Code" : "BT" },
    {"Time" : "13:30:00", "Code" : "CO" },
    {"Time" : "13:30:00", "Code" : "GO" }
]
```

So the pattern is either `CO -> GO` or `GO -> BT` or `CO -> GO -> BT -> CO -> GO`.

There might be a good old `if else` solution, but I'm looking for a nice and easy to use LINQ solution. (e.g. `list.OrderBy( x => x.Time ).RearrangeBy( x => x.Code, pattern );` )

**EDIT**

The custom ordering must only take place, when the codes are in the same time slot.

The easiest pattern is:

```
CO -> GO -> CO -> GO -> CO -> GO
```

But there is also a possibility that a BT can be present:

```
CO -> GO -> BT -> CO -> GO -> BT -> CO -> GO -> BT -> CO
```

But there is also a possibility that there is only one BT:

```
CO -> GO -> BT -> GO -> GO -> CO -> GO -> CO -> GO
CO -> GO -> CO -> GO -> BT -> CO -> GO -> CO -> GO
CO -> GO -> CO -> GO -> CO -> GO -> BT -> CO -> GO
CO -> GO -> BT -> CO -> GO -> CO -> GO -> BT -> CO -> GO
```

So tha major pattern is `CO -> GO -> BT`.

**EDIT 2 Solved**

I created an extension method. May be this code is useful for somebody. (room for improvement)

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> RearrangeByPattern<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> list, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEnumerable<TKey> pattern)
{
    var groups = list.GroupBy(keySelector).OrderBy(x => pattern.IndexOf(x.Key));
    var maxOccurences = groups.Select(x => x.Count()).Max();

    var result = new List<TSource>();
    for (var i = 0; i < maxOccurences; i++)
    {
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            if (group.Count() > i)
            {
                result.Add(group.ElementAt(i));
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now I can use it like this:

```
var list = new List<TimeAndCode>();
... // add values
var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => x.Date).RearrangeByPattern( x => x.Code, new string[] { "CO", "GO", "BT" });
```

Comment: @MindSwipe can't use ThenBy, then it does not order by the neccessary pattern.

Comment: I don't think you can use the default order functionality here (not even with a custom-implemented comparator), since sometimes `CO < GO` and sometimes `GO < CO` (if there is a `BT` in between). I'd probably "group by" time, then run a custom method to create the pattern, and then expand those groups into separate entries again (SelectMany).

Comment: Ahh, you need a specific pattern, then there's no default functionality for you, you'll have to roll your own implementation. I'm also pretty sure you won't be able to do it with LINQ or iterators as you need to read the current, previous and next item in the enumeration

Comment: You mean you want the second occurrence of a CO to be sorted after the first occurrence of a BT, at 13:30 ? What splits the tie for the two CO? Why is *this one* (points at whatever CO one) first and *that one* (points at any random other CO) second?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes. The JSON list represents the result after sorting.

Comment: Yes, but when looking at only the events that happen at 13:30, more than one possible ordering is valid according to your rules (since there are multiple CO and GO events in that set). How do you decide on that? And is it relevant?

Comment: Why does the BT come after CO GO CO GO at 9:30 but between the two CO GO at 13:30? (Why is 930 CO GO CO GO **BT**, and 1330 is CO GO **BT** CO GO)

Comment: @CaiusJard the code parameter is a control parameter. The result data is an input data format for a legacy programm. The data needs to be sent in a sorted way like I described (hopefully understandable)

Comment: @ArndtBieberstein The problem with the description is that your output has some ambiguities, and it is not clear how you solve them. We don't know why the result you present is correct and some other possible sorting orders are not (since there are several identical rows in the output).

Comment: @PMF yes it's like event pairs or triplets. The time component is the major rot property. Then there might be CO, GO, CO, GO in an alternating way. But there is also the possibility that after a GO event a BT event can occur. But if so a CO events should be after the BT event (if available)

Comment: You have 30 minute period so be to use GroupBy with "TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute * 30" : list.OrderBy(x => x.Time).GroupBy(x => x.Time.Ticks / (TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute * 30));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion where `TimeAndCode.Code` is an `enum` rather than a `string`.

It will always order entries with indentical timespans in a repeated `CO`, `GO`, `BT` pattern; meaning that if e.g. five entries with identical timespans has the following `Code` selection: `2 x CO`, `1 x BT`, `2 x GO`, it will always order them as `CO`, `GO`, `BT`, `CO`, `GO` (as opposed to `CO`, `GO`, `CO`, `GO`, `BT`).

I achieve this by generating an `OrderBy` property based on the timespan, an index (generated inside a nested group) and the numerical `Code` value for each entry.

Using the following types:

```
public struct TimeAndCode
{
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public Code Code { get; set; }
}

public enum Code
{
    Undefined,
    CO,
    GO,
    BT
}
```

we can write the following expression:

```
List<TimeAndCode> result = list
    .GroupBy(entry => entry.Code)
    .SelectMany(gr => gr
        .GroupBy(entry => entry.Time)
        .SelectMany(gr => gr.Select((entry, index) => (
            OrderBy: entry.Time.ToString() + index + (int)entry.Code,
            TimeAndCode: entry))))
    .OrderBy(entry => entry.OrderBy)
    .Select(entry => entry.TimeAndCode)
    .ToList();
```

where `list` is a `List<TimeAndCode>`.

---

Using example input as follows:

```
List<TimeAndCode> list = new List<TimeAndCode> 
{
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(09, 00, 00), Code = Code.GO },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(13, 30, 00), Code = Code.BT },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(09, 30, 00), Code = Code.GO },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(09, 30, 00), Code = Code.GO },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(13, 30, 00), Code = Code.GO },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(08, 00, 00), Code = Code.CO },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(09, 30, 00), Code = Code.BT },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(12, 30, 00), Code = Code.CO },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(09, 30, 00), Code = Code.CO },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(12, 30, 00), Code = Code.GO },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(13, 30, 00), Code = Code.CO },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(13, 30, 00), Code = Code.CO },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(09, 30, 00), Code = Code.CO },
    new TimeAndCode { Time = new TimeSpan(13, 30, 00), Code = Code.GO },
};
```

, after applying the Linq expression, we can then print the result

```
foreach (var entry in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Time: " + entry.Time + " Code: " + entry.Code);
}
```

and get the following output:

```
Time: 08:00:00 Code: CO
Time: 09:00:00 Code: GO
Time: 09:30:00 Code: CO
Time: 09:30:00 Code: GO
Time: 09:30:00 Code: BT
Time: 09:30:00 Code: CO
Time: 09:30:00 Code: GO
Time: 12:30:00 Code: CO
Time: 12:30:00 Code: GO
Time: 13:30:00 Code: CO
Time: 13:30:00 Code: GO
Time: 13:30:00 Code: BT
Time: 13:30:00 Code: CO
Time: 13:30:00 Code: GO
```

Comment: But then it's not to spec for 9:30 .. ?

Comment: @CaiusJard No, it's not. That's what I wanted to explain in the second paragraph. I couldn't see that OP had answered the question regarding the several possible ways of ordering such a set of `Code`s for a unique timespan, so I figured I'd suggest this, seeing as it _does_ follow the pattern that is presented by OP: "So tha major pattern is `CO -> GO -> BT`."

Comment: Indeed.. Most frustrating when they don't explain themselves..

Answer (score 1):

It's a variation of Astrid's:

```
var r =  list.GroupBy(tc => tc)
        .SelectMany(g => g.Select((tc, i) => (tc, i)))
        .OrderBy(t => (t.tc.Time, t.i, t.tc.Code))
        .Select(t => t.tc);
```

With the following precursor setup:

```
public record TimeAndCode(TimeSpan Time, Code Code);

public enum Code { CO, GO, BT }

    ...

    var list = new List<TimeAndCode> 
        {
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(8), Code.CO),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(9), Code.GO),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(9.5), Code.CO),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(9.5), Code.GO),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(9.5), Code.GO),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(9.5), Code.CO),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(9.5), Code.BT),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(12.5), Code.CO),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(12.5), Code.GO),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(13.5), Code.CO),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(13.5), Code.BT),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(13.5), Code.GO),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(13.5), Code.CO),
            new (TimeSpan.FromHours(13.5), Code.GO),
        };
```

TimeAndCode is a record, which means it gains some useful properties for sorting and comparing. It can be simply grouped because it is automatically equal to another TimeAndCode with the same data

Grouping by the time and code results in a list-of-lists; the two `9:30 CO`s go in a list. Passing this to `Select((tc,i)` means that `i` is 0 for the first and 1 for the second etc.. All we do with this is promote it to a tuple of the `tc` and the `i` because we'll need them later, and we SelectMany to undo the GroupBy that allowed us to count the same Time/Code

We OrderBy another tuple; tuples sort by their values in order, so to order by 3 things a, b, and c, we can OrderBy a tuple of `(a, b, c)`

And all that is left to do at the end is select the `tc` back to make a list of TimeAndCode, sorted something like what you want

Like Astrid's it also doesn't put the BT at the end for 9:30 - it goes in the middle, like 13:30's does.. But you haven't provided an explanation for why 9:30's BT is at the end...